# Wildcard that executes command once for each match

Tags: bash, shell, wildcard, zsh

## Alternate title: How to loop without a loop or xargs.

Recently, I switched to zsh because of its many features. I'm curious: Is there a feature which expands wildcards such that the command is executed once for each match instead of only one time for all matches at once.

#### Example

The command `ebook-convert input_file output_file [options]` accepts just one input file. When I want to convert multiple files, I have to execute the command multiple times manually or use a loop, for instance:

```
for i in *.epub; do 
    ebook-convert "$i" .mobi
done
```

What I'd like is a wildcard that functions like the loop so that I can save a few keystrokes. Let said wildcard be `⁂`. The command

```
ebook-convert ⁂.epub .mobi
```

should expand to

```
ebook-convert 1stMatch.epub .mobi
ebook-convert 2ndMatch.epub .mobi
ebook-convert 3rdMatch.epub .mobi
...
```

#### Still interested in other answers

I accepted an answer that works for me (thanks to Grisha Levit). But if you know other shells with such a feature, alternative commands which are shorter than writing a loop, or even a way to extend zsh with the wanted wildcard your answers are appreciated.

Comment: Array programming languages like APL will automatically map a function over a higher-rank input, but I don't know of this feature in any shell. The closest I can think of is how loops can be expressed quite concisely in PowerShell: `ls *.epub | % {ebook-convert $_ .mobi}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> so that I can save a few keystrokes

OK, so let's say you typed out

```
ebook-convert *.epub .mobi
```

…and now you realized that this isn't going to work — you need to write a loop.  What would you normally do? Probably something like:

- add `; done` to the end of the line
- hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to go the beginning of the line
- type `for i in`…
- etc…

#### This looks like a good fit for readline keyboard macro:

Let's write this out the steps in terms of readline [commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bindable-Readline-Commands) and regular keypresses:

```
end-of-line                    # (start from the end for consistency)
; done                         # type in the loop closing statement
character-search-backward *    # go back to the where the glob is
shell-backward-word            # (in case the glob is in the mid-word)
shell-kill-word                # "cut" the word with the glob
"$i"                           # type the loop variable
beginning-of-line              # go back to the start of the line
for i in                       # type the beginning of the loop opening
yank                           # "paste" the word with the glob
; do                           # type the end of the loop opening
```

#### Creating the binding:

For any readline command used above that does not have a key-binding, we need to create one.  We also need to create a binding for the new macro that we are creating.

Unless you've already done a lot of readline customization, running the commands below will set the bindings up for the current shell.  This uses default bindings like `\C-e` ➙ `end-of-line`.

```
bind '"\eB": shell-backward-word'
bind '"\eD": shell-kill-word'

bind '"\C-i": "\C-e; done\e\C-]*\eB\eD \"$i\"\C-afor i in\C-y; do "'
```

<sup>The bindings can also go into the [`inputrc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Sample-Init-File) file for persistence.</sup>

#### Using the shortcut:

After setting things up:

1. Type in something like

   ```
   ebook-convert *.epub .mobi
   ```
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>
3. The line will transform into

   ```
   for i in *.epub; do ebook-convert "$i" .mobi; done
   ```

If you want to run the command right away, you can modify the macro to append a `\C-j` as the last keypress, which will trigger `accept-line` (same as hitting <kbd>Return</kbd>).

Comment: Cool practicality prevails! Bravo!

Comment: That's a very clever and practical idea. I leave this question open for another day to gain more answers. Maybe there is a built-in solution, otherwise your answer will be accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You could checkout [`zargs`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zargs) in zsh.

> This function has a similar purpose to GNU xargs. Instead of reading lines of arguments from the standard input, it takes them from the command line
>
> [`zshcontrib(1): OTHER FUNCTIONS, zargs`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zargs)

So, we could write:

```shell
autoload -Uz zargs
zargs -I⁂ -- *.epub -- ebook-convert ⁂ .mobi
```

---

PS: you could find [`zmv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv) is handy if you need to capture some portions of patterns for building commands.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to `zargs` and `zmv`, both look quite useful. `zargs` is actually 4 or 6 characters shorter than a loop, but I would probably stick to the loop because `zargs` isn't *that* much shorter and I'm more used to write loops. `zmv` looks very promising. Unfortunately `zmv -P program ...` calls `program -- oldname newname`, meaning that it isn't an option for my example case since `ebook-convert` doesn't support `--`.

Comment: Oh good catch! `-P/-p` has been added for `zmv` since zsh-5.0.3 according to https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/commit/669c070efe06d1820ccb32adaa6b1512279401ab.

Answer (score 2):

The `for` loop has a shortened form that you might like:

```
for f (*.epub) ebook-convert $f .mobi
```

Comment: Wow, that's very nice. I might combine your solution with Grisha Levit's solution. Thank you!

Comment: While bash has some undocumented `for` loop syntax variations, the one in this answer is for **`zsh`** only.

Answer (score 0):

You could make yourself a script that does this :

```
#!/bin/bash

command="$1"
shift
if
  [[ $# -lt 3 ]]
then
  echo "Usage: command file/blog arg1, arg2..."
  exit 1
fi

declare -a files=()
while [ "$1" != "--" ]
do
  [ "$1" ] || continue
  files+=("$1")
  shift
done

if
  [ "$1" != "--" ]
then
  echo "Separator not found : end file list with --"
  exit 1
fi
shift

for file in "${files[@]}"
do
  "$command" "$file" "$@"
done
```

You cal call this like this (assumes the script is called `apply_to`).

```
apply_to command /dir/* arg1, arg2...
```

**EDIT**

I modified the code to insert filenames at the beginning of the command.

Comment: The script won't work for `ebook-convert`, because we cannot specify the constant 2nd parameter `.mobi` after the variable first parameter `*.epub`. Instead of extending the script, we are better of using `xargs` or `zargs`. Thank you for your effort anyway :)

Comment: @Socowi  Modified the code to have the command name, then the file/glob, then `--` separator, and finally the (option) arguments.  The script could be made to handle both either with an option.